# Google compute engine Change Zones

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I saw the following warning message when I connected to the compute engine:

"This zone is deprecated and will go offline soon. When the zone goes offline, all VMs in this zone will be destroyed.

In this case, my machine will be deleted, am I right? Shouldn't it be migrated online normally? How can I move my machine to a different zone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Google has released new tools in the sdk for moving instances and disks. First you need to update the group tools:

```
 $ gcloud components update
```

Then you can move instances as follows:

```
 $ gcloud compute instances move my-vm --zone europe-west1-a --destination-zone europe-west1-d
```

Or disks:

```
 $ gcloud compute disks move my-disk --zone europe-west1-a --destination-zone europe-west1-d
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

You will need to migrate manually for zone deprecation

Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/zones#zone_deprecation

You can find instructions on migrating here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#moving_an_instance_between_zones

Comment: I can confirm that this migration process works, I had to do the same myself.

Comment: HTTPError 400: Invalid resource usage: 'Instance is a UEFI-enabled instance and does not support MoveInstance.'

I just got this message, How can I disable UEFI?

Comment: @ExpertWeblancer when creating an instance in GCE, you can select a boot disk image that supports "Shielded VM features".  You can then enable "Secure Boot" in the Security section of the VM creation.  This mode ensures that the VM is running a verified bootloader and kernel on boot. see: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/security-simplified-making-shielded-vm-default-compute-engine